# Didn't understand relationship 'SetupEntity' in field path Error in Salesforce Workbench

Tags: soql, workbench

I am trying to query profiles having visibility with some applications. I used the following query:

`SELECT Id, SetupEntityId, Parent.Profile.Name, SetupEntityType FROM SetupEntityAccess WHERE SetupEntityType = 'TabSet' AND SetupEntityId IN ('02uD0000000GIiMIAW')`

I get following results:

```
Id                       SetupEntityId           SetupEntityType      PermissionSet.Profile.Name 

*some 18 digit id*       *some 18 digit id*      TabSet               Standard User
*some 18 digit id*       *some 18 digit id*      TabSet               System Administrator
```

But there is also a requirement wherein I have to display the application label instead of some 18 digit ID , so I modified my query to:

`SELECT Id, SetupEntityId, SetupEntity.Label, Parent.Profile.Name, SetupEntityType FROM SetupEntityAccess WHERE SetupEntityType = 'TabSet' AND SetupEntityId IN ('02uD0000000GIiMIAW')`

Upon running the query, I am now getting the following error:

[image]

I am just trying to get the label of the application itself, but I am now stuck.

Hoping someonce can help me on this.

Comment: SetupEntittyId is polymorphic and per describe there is no relationship field defined to use. You're going to need two queries

Comment: Not sure if I am using the correct object, but I also noticed that upon query. Also, are there any objects I can use to get the app permissions per profile? I thought `SetupEntityId` pertains to the applicationID itself so I assumed that it is already directly linked.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the sheer number of tables involved, you can't use the SetupEntity relationship; in this way, it behaves more like a "special text field" rather than a "lookup relationship" field. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm) does not specifically call this out, but if you check the examples, you'll notice there's no example of using the SetupEntityId field as a relationship. You'd need to make separate queries for each name that you need, which may mean querying hundreds of times (so, you might need to do it in chunks, depending on complexity).